# Recibir datos desde Serial Port RS232 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serialport

Tengo que recibir datos desde una balanza.
El código que utilizo es el siguiente;

```
SerialPort spPuertoSerie = new SerialPort();
spPuertoSerie.PortName = "COM1";
spPuertoSerie.Handshake = Handshake.None;
spPuertoSerie.BaudRate = 9600;
spPuertoSerie.Parity = Parity.None;
spPuertoSerie.StopBits = StopBits.One;
spPuertoSerie.DataBits = 8;
```

Comienzo la escucha del puerto

```
spPuertoSerie.Open();
```

y lo muestro en un textBox correctamente. El problema es que no me muestra bien los datos, con eso me refiero a dos cosas:
LA PRIMERA: El dato en el textBox parpadea y se alterna entre números y símbolos. 
LA SEGUNDA: El número que muestra no es el correcto, mientras la balanza me muestra el número 1800, el TexBox solo 800. O si la balanza muestra 13440, el TexBox solo 440.
El dueño de la balanza me comentó que quizás el problema radique en el carácter de control, pero no se como avanzar. 
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Por experiencia propia, considero que los problemas se deben al método que utilizas.

1. El problema del parpadeo se debe a que el textbox va mostrando la data que va obteniendo. Es decir, captura parte de la data y la muestra, y así sucesivamente.
2. Va relacionado con lo anterior, el textbox al final muestra solo los últimos 3 caracteres.

Te recomendaría que trabajes con el siguiente evento y método para que captures toda la data en un string y obtengas la información que quieres mostrar.

```
private void spPuertoSerie_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string DataIn = String.Empty;
    //Thread.Sleep(1000);//Puedes darle un retardo si lo consideras necesario.
    DataIn = spPuertoSerie.ReadExisting();
}
```